# Return Previous and Next Value in Sequence Based on Current Value

Tags: sql-server, sequence

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [opTest] 
(
    [name] varchar(50),
    [task] varchar(50),
    [desc] varchar(100),
    [seq] varchar(5)
)

INSERT INTO [opTest] VALUES 
('Yale', 'Paint', 'Prime Part', '100'),
('Yale', 'Paint', 'Paint Part', '200'),
('Yale', 'Assembly', 'Front Wheel Assembly', '100'),
('Yale', 'Assembly', 'Rear Wheel Assembly', '200'),
('Yale', 'Assembly', 'Chain Assembly', '300'),
('Yale', 'Assembly', 'HUB Assembly', '400'),
('Yale', 'Assembly', 'Final Assembly', '500'),
('Yale', 'CNC Inspection', 'CNC Machine Inspection', '100')

+------+----------------+------------------------+-----+
| name | task           | desc                   | seq |
+------+----------------+------------------------+-----+
| Yale | Paint          | Prime Part             | 100 |
| Yale | Paint          | Paint Part             | 200 |
| Yale | Assembly       | Front Wheel Assembly   | 100 |
| Yale | Assembly       | Rear Wheel Assembly    | 200 |
| Yale | Assembly       | Chain Assembly         | 300 |
| Yale | Assembly       | HUB Assembly           | 400 |
| Yale | Assembly       | Final Assembly         | 500 |
| Yale | CNC Inspection | CNC Machine Inspection | 100 |
+------+----------------+------------------------+-----+
```

I am want to output the data with the Previous, Current and Next task in the sequence.  I want it to look like this:

```
+------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Name | Task           | Description            | Prev Task | Curr Task | Next Task |
+------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Yale | Assembly       | Front Wheel Assembly   | NULL      | 100       | 200       |
| Yale | Assembly       | Rear Wheel Assembly    | 100       | 200       | 300       |
| Yale | Assembly       | Chain Assembly         | 200       | 300       | 400       |
| Yale | Assembly       | HUB Assembly           | 300       | 400       | 500       |
| Yale | Assembly       | Final Assembly         | 400       | 500       | NULL      |
| Yale | CNC Inspection | CNC Machine Inspection | NULL      | 100       | NULL      |
| Yale | Paint          | Prime Part             | NULL      | 100       | 200       |
| Yale | Paint          | Paint Part             | 100       | 200       | NULL      |
+------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I am using the following query and I can't figure out why it's not working.  I did a simple test with a single field table and it worked.  The only diff was that the field was int in my test, but I am casting to int, so it shouldn't be a problem.

```
SELECT
    [Name] AS [Name],
    [Task] AS [Task],
    [Desc] AS [Description],
    (SELECT TOP(1) t1.[Seq] 
     FROM [opTest] t1 
     WHERE CAST(t1.[Seq] AS int) > CAST([Seq] AS int) 
     ORDER BY t1.[Seq] ASC) AS [Prev Task],
    [Seq] AS [Curr Task],
    (SELECT TOP(1) t1.[Seq] 
     FROM [opTest] t1 
     WHERE CAST(t1.[Seq] AS int) < CAST([Seq] AS int) 
     ORDER BY t1.[Seq] DESC) AS [Next Task]
FROM 
    [opTest]
ORDER BY 
    [Name] ASC, [Task] ASC, [Seq] ASC
```

That returns this result:

```
+------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Name | Task           | Description            | Prev Task | Curr Task | Next Task |
+------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Yale | Assembly       | Front Wheel Assembly   | NULL      | 100       | NULL      |
| Yale | Assembly       | Rear Wheel Assembly    | NULL      | 200       | NULL      |
| Yale | Assembly       | Chain Assembly         | NULL      | 300       | NULL      |
| Yale | Assembly       | HUB Assembly           | NULL      | 400       | NULL      |
| Yale | Assembly       | Final Assembly         | NULL      | 500       | NULL      |
| Yale | CNC Inspection | CNC Machine Inspection | NULL      | 100       | NULL      |
| Yale | Paint          | Prime Part             | NULL      | 100       | NULL      |
| Yale | Paint          | Paint Part             | NULL      | 200       | NULL      |
+------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Why am I not getting the previous and next sequences?

Comment: Why don't you just use `LAG()` or `LEAD()` ?

Comment: These subqueries are going to return *any* row with a lower/higher `seq` irrespective of whether it's a different `Name` and `Task`. You could use `LEAD/LAG`, but either way you need to think how you want to partition the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your query, you should use table alias and prefix all the column name with alias.

Your problem is you didn't specify the alias for the second column [Seq]. Is it from `t1` or `[opTest]` ? SQL Server assumed it to be from `t1`

```
  CAST(t1.[Seq] AS int) 
> CAST([Seq] AS int)    -- this is from which table ?
```

To fix your query, add appropriate alias to the column. Eg.`T.[Seq]`

---

```
SELECT
    [Name]  AS [Name],
    [Task]  AS [Task],
    [Desc]  AS [Description],
    ( SELECT TOP(1) t1.[Seq] FROM [opTest] t1 
      WHERE CAST(t1.[Seq] AS int) > CAST(T.[Seq] AS int) 
      ORDER BY t1.[Seq] ASC )
            AS [Prev Task],
    [Seq]   AS [Curr Task],
    ( SELECT TOP(1) t1.[Seq] FROM [opTest] t1 
      WHERE CAST(t1.[Seq] AS int) < CAST(T.[Seq] AS int) 
      ORDER BY t1.[Seq] DESC )
            AS [Next Task]
  FROM [opTest] T
ORDER BY [Name] ASC, [Task] ASC, [Seq] ASC
```

You can use `LEAD()` or `LAG()` and avoid the use of sub-query

Comment: Interesting.  In my little test I didn't need the table alias on the main table.  Adding it worked.  I was not aware of the LEAD and LAG functions.  I gave them a try and they worked very well, very easily, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems.

First, in both subqueries you compare the field [seq] with itself. You have to be explicit in both [seq] mentions of the subqueries about which level of the query you want compared. When not explicit, it just defaults to the current level.

Second, you only filter the [seq] in both subqueries. Which means it will show the previous or next value for it regardless of it being actually related to the [task].

Also, just like the previous answer mentions. Why not just use LEAD and LAG functions?